# How do I crop an image without loading it into memory using Java

Tags: java, image, image-processing, crop

Is there a way to crop an image without having the load the entire image into memory and cropping it then?

The scenario is that I have a really really big image file and I have a list of rectangular coordinates that I need to crop out of the big image. The image is so huge I can't directly load it into memory. Is there a technique I can stream the image and sort of find the start and end points to crop? Don't mind if I have to perform this step many times for each set of coordinates. Oh yeah, assuming the images are of format JPG/PNG/TIFF which ever one is easiest to work with.

Should be able to run on Windows and Linux should there be any dependencies on native libraries.

Thanks.

Comment: Check out im4java and JMagick, both of which use ImageMagick under the hood.  This question has also been answered several times on StackOverflow.

Comment: Not sure if there's anything in Java that you could use but the [`LargeTIFFTools`](http://www.imnc.in2p3.fr/pagesperso/deroulers/software/largetifftools/) utility is specifically designed for this purpose.

Comment: I forgot to mention that this should work on Windows as well as Linux, but luckily there is a windows binary :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `libvips` to do this - it is available for Linux, OSX and Windows.

To get set up, let's use ImageMagick to create a big image (10,000x10,000) that is difficult to compress because it is full of random noise:

```
convert -size 10000x10000 xc:gray +noise random  \
   -fill red  -draw "rectangle 0,0 100,100"      \
   -fill blue -draw "rectangle 9900,9900 10000,10000" BigBoy.tif
```

Reduced in size, it looks like this, with a red rectangle in the top-left and a blue rectangle in the bottom-right if you look closely:

[image]

and weighs in at 800 MB:

```
-rw-r--r--@  1 mark  staff  800080278  5 May 12:08 BigBoy.tif
```

Now let's use `libvips` (just at the command-line) to extract the top-left and bottom-right corners (which are readily identifiable - did you see what I did there?):

```
vips im_extract_area BigBoy.tif topleft.jpg 0 0 200 200 --vips-leak
memory: high-water mark 118.85 MB
```

[image]

```
vips im_extract_area BigBoy.tif bottomright.jpg 9800 9800 200 200 --vips-leak
memory: high-water mark 118.85 MB
```

[image]

Both commands used around 120MB of memory. I don't believe there are Java bindings for `libvips`, but I presume you can `fork()` and `exec()` stuff or use something like C's `system()` function.

Comment: Thanks, this is great. Yes I can definitely run the commands from Java as a process or even make my own JNI class to access it which isn't too much work.